# Contour integral on closed contour C that contains a singularity

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, cauchy-integral-formula

I wish to compute 
$$ \int_C \frac{\sin z}{(z+1)^7}\ \text{d}z $$
where $C$ is the circle of radius $6$, centre $0$, positively oriented.

Now I know that $f(z) = \frac{\sin z}{(z+1)^7}$ is analytic on $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{-1\}$ since $f$ is the composition and quotient of analytic functions.

I tried to use the Cauchy-Goursat Extension which says
$$ \int_C f(z)\ \text{d}z = \int_{C'} f(z)\ \text{d}z $$
where $C'$ is the circle of radius $1$, center $-1$, positively oriented. However this only reformulates the problem.

My second thought was to integrate around $-1$ with a keyhole-like contour with an $\varepsilon$-wide cut and show it goes to $0$ but this feels unnecessarily complicated. Am I missing something that'd simplify things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pole $z=-1$ is inside the circle $C$. Hence, by the [Residue Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem), since the pole $z=-1$ has order $n=7$, we have that (see [HERE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_(complex_analysis)#Limit_formula_for_higher_order_poles))
$$\int_C \frac{\sin z}{(z+1)^7}\ \text{d}z=2\pi i\cdot \mbox{Res}\left(\frac{\sin z}{(z+1)^7},-1\right)=2\pi i
\cdot \frac{ D^{(6)}(\sin(z))_{z=-1}}{6!}.$$